# ng-bootstrap modal opens component, but places html-selector

Tags: angular, flexbox, ng-bootstrap, ng-modal

I am using [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/modal/examples) within my angular 4 application. With ngbModal I open a modal. The modal content is placed in a separate component: `selector: 'my-modal-component'`.

**Component one (click to open modal in the component.ts):**

```
this.spModalService.open(MyModalComponent, 'sm');
```

**Component two (the content of the modal):**

```
<div class="modal-header"> (..) </div>
<div class="modal-body"> (..) </div>
<div class="modal-footer"> (..) </div>
```

So far so good. The class `.modal-content` gets the calsses `d-flex` and `flex-column` to make sure the `.modal-header`, -`body` and -`footer` know what to do (divide the height vertically).

But: because I am giving ngbModal a component as the content of the modal, it places a selector-tag in the HTML:

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <my-modal-component>
        <div class="modal-header"> (..) </div>
        <div class="modal-body"> (..) </div>
        <div class="modal-footer"> (..) </div>
    </my-modal-component>
</div>
```

Because of this HTML-selector, my flexbox styling isn't working anymore, because the `.modal-header`, -`body` and -`footer` are no longer direct children of the `.modal-content` class.

Does anyone know if the selector can be ignored?

**EDIT: This is my desired result:**

```
<div class="modal-content">
    <div class="modal-header"> (...) </div>
    <div class="modal-body"> (...) </div>
    <div class="modal-footer"> (...) </div>
</div>
```

I've been googling and reading like crazy, but have not found anyone with the same problem and question.

Answer (score 0):

try loading your scss pages in dirent way like :
    import 'style-loader!./your-scss-file-name.scss';

Comment: when you import scss file in the regular way it adds a generated number in the end of the selector, and that is way it doesn't effect another components.

Comment: I would like angular to ignore the component-selector and not generate it in the DOM:
`<div class="modal-content">`
   `<div class="modal-header"> (...) </div>`
    `<div class="modal-body"> (...) </div>`
   `<div class="modal-footer"> (...) </div>`
`</div>`